# How can I put Brood War into a window?

Tags: starcraft

I'm interested in livestreaming Brood War until I get StarCraft II. Kind of a kickoff event. It would be super helpful to get StarCraft into a window. I've tried a few things, but they all seem to not work, most likely because of how old BW is.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [W-MODE plugin](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/W-Mode) for launchers like [ChaosLauncher](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/Chaoslauncher) will make StarCraft run in a window. Works perfectly, even under 64-bit Windows 7.

With this plugin, you can lock the mouse cursor inside the game window to avoid accidentally moving the mouse outside when trying to scroll, you can lock the window to prevent it from being moved, and you can have it double the window size to make the game take up more of the screen (which may be helpful, since Starcraft runs at a pretty low resolution and it may be hard to see things otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is an option for you, but since I use GNU/Linux I run Starcraft with [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/). You can ask Wine to start the application in a window and define it's resolution.

You could also use it inside a virtual machine running in a window.